# How to migrate oracle to amazon rds

Tags: amazon-rds

iam new to Amazon RDS. I want to migrate oracle data to RDS. How do it? Is there any middleware or else directly we can?.Eeven in later i want to load incremental data too. 
The database schema is same or it will change.
what are plus and usel point about RDS.
Its very inneed.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What have you found till date about your question?

Comment: Please  mention what have you found and what problem you are facing so that OPs could understand your problem precisely and help you out.

Comment: Have you created a free account and created a database yet? Do you have an Oracle DBA? What type of applications use this Oracle data?